# Text File doesn't append ("a") after opened in write mode ("w") in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, append, text-files

After opening a text file in "w" mode and write something in it; after when i wanna open the same file in append mode (coz i wanna keep the contents on the first line the same) it overwrites the content instead of adding below it.

Below are the sample:

Code:

```
hand1 = open("test.txt", "w")
hand1.write("Good Morning")
hand1.close()

hand2 = open("test.txt", "a")
hand2.write("\n" + "Hello")
hand2.close()
```

text file:

```
Good Morning

Hello
```

No matter how many times i run this python file, it still gives me the same output which is:

textfile:

```
Good Morning

Hello
```

where i expect the output to be (if i run the python file multiple times):

text file:

```
Good Morning
Hello
Hello
Hello
```

Anyone knows how to fix this? "Hello" could be in there for multiple lines if the "w" mode isnt opened.

Comment: When you run it again, you're rerunning the whole thing, not just the "append" part.

Comment: From the code it seems you open the file in `w` mode first and then `a` mode. So everytime you run this file it will first open it in write mode thereby overwriting the earlier contents.

Answer (score 4):

Every time you run the script, you will create a new file that overwrites your old file. You can add an if statement to check if your file already exists, and if not, create one.

```
import os

if not os.path.isfile("test.txt"): 

    hand1 = open("test.txt", "w")
    hand1.write("Good Morning")
    hand1.close()

hand2 = open("test.txt", "a")
hand2.write("\n" + "Hello")
hand2.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

From the code it seems you open the file in `w` mode first and then `a` mode. So everytime you run this file it will first open it in write mode thereby overwriting the earlier contents. Also when you run the script again it will not just execute append part, but will run the entire script. If you want that behavior you can do this.

1. Pass an argument as `-w` to `write` to the file or `-a` to `append` to the file or both `-wa` to do `write` and `append` to the file.
2. Based on the argument decide on which part of the code to execute.

So possible ways to execute your script can be `python test.py -w`, `python test.py -a`, `python test.py -wa`

Comment: Oh i see..... mmm definetely learnt new stuff, thank you